# Matlab imshow update image at old position and magnification

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I currently use Matlab's imshow to output an image at every iteration of a diffusion filter process, i.e. multiple times per second.
Sometimes during filtering I want a closer look at specific image parts.
However, when using the ('Parent', handle) name-value pair for imshow the magnification and position gets reset.

Is there a way to update the underlying image but having the magnification and position intact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the `cdata` in the current axis to your new data matrix which will keep all other settings the same. If this is in a loop, you probably need to call `drawnow`. E.g:

```
x=randn(100);
figure;imagesc(x);
```

Now zoom  / pan / do whatever manipulations you want.

```
f=gca;
x=randn(100);
f.Children.CData = x;
```

This method of updating of child data is recommended by Matlab as more efficient than destroying the axis child `Image` and recreating each frame (can't remember the source, it was in one of the help files).

Edit: Just remembered that this syntax won't work on older versions of matlab (pre 2015 or so). In that case, use get/set syntax:

```
set(get(gca,'Children'),'CData',x);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
I just did not notice the structure of the handle before.

Comment: @Kapt.Brackbier: It can be confusing at the start. But what helped me most instead of only reading the documentation, is to always use `get` for different types of handles (axes-handle, figure-handle) and dig deep into the structure - you'll get to know quite a lot about available properties, some of them you'd probably not even thought of. E.g.: `f=figure; plot(...); get(f);` or `figure; plot(...); hAx=gca; get(hAx);` just have a look and learn :-)